# Create a meteor.js sitemap

Tags: javascript, meteor

Sitemaps are cool. If I want one for my meteor project, I guess I could do one of the following:

1. Hard code a sitemap.xml file and put in the /public/ folder. Not dynamic, but easy for google to find. Might be sufficient for apps with few sub pages.
2. (Haven't tried this at all) Create a dynamic sitemap using the meteor Router at /sitemap.xml (?) and output this as XML. Dynamic, but won't be very easy for google to find as it's loaded dynamically (maybe with the spiderable package?)

But neither is very satisfying to me. I would want it to be dynamic but yet stored in an (preferably) static file that's easy to find by Google. Or something like that.

**What's the best way?**

Answer (score 3):

if there is a way you could use the client side router to dynamically generate a sitemap, It might be possible with Meteor Router

You need [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and meteor's http. Meteor router has a prequisite of [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite), which it looks like you already have.

So the first step is to make a route for that sitemap.xml with server side routing:

```
Meteor.Router.add('sitemap.xml', function() {
    //get sitemap data (below)
    return generated_sitemap;
});
```

and a function that generates the sitemap:

We need that `router.js`, which is unfortunately only run on the client. So we need to fetch it with meteor.http. The `router.js` file basically contains the `Meteor.Router.add` bit of your router code. Adjust the url to wherever your `router.js` file might be stored

```
routerdata = Meteor.http.get("http://localhost:3000/client/router.js").content
```

We then need to parse the router data out of there (make sure you use the var so scoping doesn't ruin the actual router)

**Server side js**

```
Meteor.Router.add('/sitemap.xml', function() {
    routerdata = Meteor.http.get("http://localhost:3000/client/router.js").content 
    var Meteor = {};
    Meteor.Router = {add:function(input) {return input}};

    //drag the data out of the routerdata, eval is quick and dirty but you could shackle it down further
    routers = eval(routerdata);

    //now generate the sitemap.xml data

    xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
    for(var url in routers) {
        xmldata+="<url>\n";
        xmldata+="<loc>"+url+"</loc>\n";
        xmldata+="<lastmod>2013-03-03</lastmod>\n";
        xmldata+="<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n";
        xmldata+="<priority>0.8</priority>\n";
        xmldata+="</url>\n";
    }

    xmldata+="</urlset>";

    return xmldata;
});
```

You might need to customize it a bit further to exactly how you want it. I can't say i've tried the above im not really conversant with how to optimally use sitemaps but it might get you a start

Comment: I actually started writing something similar yesterday, though I do want an actual file for the sitemap.xml (feels safest for google), and got the node.js fs module to write the file and everything. Thanks for your reply and I'll post back here if I get to anything worth sharing.

Answer (score 2):

this package looks promising:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/sitemaps